# BroadcastReceiver registered in a activity never get called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 Activity one is sending a broadcust and another receiving. But receiver never get called  -

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.aj.SHOWTOAST";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendBroadcast(View v) {
    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
    broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
}
```

**ToastDisplay**

```
public class ToastDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.aj.SHOWTOAST";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toast_display);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
}

private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onReceive: SMS SENT!!");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS SENT!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ToastDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.aj.SHOWTOAST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: There can only be 1 activity active at any given time. You can't send a broadcast from 1 activity to another, the 2nd activity is not going to be resumed. If you need something to happen in the 2nd activity, start it with some bundle in the start intent that tells it why it was started.

Comment: Two obvious mistake here!    1)  Your inner class should be declared static.   Just put static in front of the name.   2)  When you specify in inner class, you must give the name of the container class also in the reference to the inner class.    In your case you gave .ToastDisplay as the name of the inner class, which will have the package name appended in front.   But there is no name of the container class.    Try putting to put this as name ".MainActivity.ToastDisplay" or try to put the full package name + container classs + inner class as name.

Comment: @user3646774 Thanks man I resolved the issue. Please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can put broad cast receiver in your by this way also.

```
     public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";
    // Receive Message through Broadcast Receiver...
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String receiver = intent.getStringExtra("receiver");
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + receiver, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile_verify);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //registering the receiver...
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregistering the receiver...
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver can be called through the following intent. You can use this intent any where to call this broadcast receiver. For example there are two activity and in those two activities you are using this receiver and you calling this intent from some other class which handles server response or database result. Whichever activity is in front that activities receiver will be called.i.e., activity one is in front if you are calling this receiver intent means then receiver in the activity one will be triggered.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
 intent.putExtra("receiver", "testMessage");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the broadcast is going to happen within the app then it is good to use `LocalBroadCastManager`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.aj.SHOWTOAST";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendBroadcast(View v) {
   Intent broadcast = new Intent();
   broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
} 
}

public class ToastDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.aj.SHOWTOAST";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_toast_display);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //your code here
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));    }
}
```

Comment: in the above code there is no call to `sendBroadcast()`. make sure you called that method. Also the BroadCastReceiver in ToastDisplayActivity should be registered at least once in order to receive broadcast. check that too.

Answer (score -1):

You cant send boradcast one activity to another activity. So you have to do it like below.

First implement the Receiver as a separate class.

Receiver.java:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public Receiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.aj.SHOWTOAST";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendBroadcast(View v) {
        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

And manifest should be as below.

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.aj.SHOWTOAST"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial - 
http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/